# Agconnect - API 'android.registerTransform' is removed

Tags: android, huawei-developers

After migrating to gradle 8.x, I can't build the app because the latest Huawei AppGallery dependency  `com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.0.300` still not compatible with gradle 8.

So is there any solutions other than reverting to gradle 7 ?

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.huawei.agconnect'.
   > API 'android.registerTransform' is removed.

     For more information, see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#transform-api.
     To determine what is calling android.registerTransform, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
```

Answer (score 8):

Finally I found the solution [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-common-faq-0000001063210244#section17273113244910)..

Just add this property to `gradle.properties`

```
apmsInstrumentationEnabled=false
```

Comment: Solution 1: Update the plugin to 1.9.1.300 or later.

Answer (score 5):

Please Update the AGConnect plugin to letest. Huawei has updated To 8.0+

Version **1.9.1.300**, released on 2023-07-04

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-sdk-changenotes-0000001058732550#section1850181717218

[Screen shot of release notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB5kH.png)

Answer (score 1):

there new 1.9.1.300 update with compatible gradle 8.x
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-sdk-changenotes-0000001058732550#section1850181717218

Answer (score 0):

apmsInstrumentationEnabled=false
it solved my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).